# python Reportlab two items in the same row on a Paragraph

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

I would like to align two text in the same row, on the left and on the right:

TEXT1                           TEXT2

and in the same line left align an image and center a text:

IMAGE           TEXT

How is it possible?

That's my code:

```
Story=[]

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Center', alignment=TA_CENTER))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Left', alignment=TA_LEFT))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Right', alignment=TA_RIGHT))


ptext = '<font size=15><b>{0}</b></font>'.format("TITLE")
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Center"]))

Story.append(Spacer(10, 20))

ptext = '<font size=10>TEXT1 </font>'
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))

ptext = '<font size=10>CODICE OPERATORE</font>'
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))

Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))



signature = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, user.attr.get("signature"))
im = Image(signature, 80, 80)
im.hAlign ='RIGHT'

ptext = '<font size=10>Firma</font>'

Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))

Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Right"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
Story.append(im)

Story.append(PageBreak())

doc.build(Story)
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a `Table`. The table can have its own style and the items (Paragraph, Image, ...) can also have their own style, that way you can have differently aligned items within the table cells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `Table`. The table can have its own style and the items (`Paragraph`, `Image`, ...) can also have their own style, that way you can have differently aligned items within the table cells

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_RIGHT

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style_right = ParagraphStyle(name='right', parent=styles['Normal'], alignment=TA_RIGHT)
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("my_doc.pdf", pagesize=A4)
Story=[]
# here you add your rows and columns, these can be platypus objects
tbl_data = [
    [Paragraph("Hello", styles["Normal"]), Paragraph("World (right)", style_right)],
    [Paragraph("Another", styles["Normal"]), Paragraph("Row (normal)", styles["Normal"])]
]
tbl = Table(tbl_data)
Story.append(tbl)
doc.build(Story)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: how to make sure the table occupies full text width?